# navigate to new page on button click in iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, navigation, uibutton, buttonclick

I am new to iPhone Developer.

i want to do navigate to new page with animation but i am unable to navigate to new page,

Here is my code snippet,

```
UIButton *Planbtn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    [Planbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

..

```
-(void)btnClicked{
    NSLog(@"btnClicked");

    PlanPage *yourViewController = [[PlanPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlanPage" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:TRUE];
    [yourViewController release];
}
```

i am able to see `btnClicked` in my Log.

**Thanks in Advance !**

Comment: you will need to link the btnClicked to your interface events outlet

Comment: post some more detail, are you implementing `UINavigationController` also?

Comment: I suppose you linked your iBoutlet if you see the NSLog. So maybe your navigationController is nil because not initialized.

Comment: see my Edit, i have added only this much of code in my project, Do i need to add anything more ?

Comment: What is essential to know is whether or not your rootViewController has a navigation Controller. You can either have an app with or without it, so it's perfectly possible your app is not a navigation-based one

Comment: my application is view based not navigation based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write these properties in `AppDelegate.h` file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourFirstViewController *yourFirstController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationControl;
```

Write this code in `AppDelegate.m` file

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
        self.yourFirstViewController = [[YourFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourFirstViewController" bundle:nil]];
        navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.yourFirstViewController];
        [self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Being your app view based, you can't push the controller, the simplest thing to do is:

```
PlanPage *yourViewController = [[PlanPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlanPage" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubView:yourViewController.view];
[yourViewController release];
```

If you want to animate it, I'm afraid you have either to implement the animation by yourself, or to add a navigation controller to do the job for you