# How to navigate to the next ViewController programmatically when the a button is pressed?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am new to iPhone apps development. In my code, in first ViewController1 I have a textfield  and a ok- button. So here

1. When I click ok button without entering a string, it shows an alert message.
2. When I enter the string and then press ok button, it should navigate to next ViewController2.

I am able to do the 1st part correctly when I have not connected the ok-button to the ViewController2 in Interface Builder. But when I connect, it navigates and then shows alert message.
Please tell me how to navigate to ViewController2 programmatically after I enter the string and press ok button.

This is how my code looks for Ok- button:

```
-(IBAction) okButton: (id) sender
{
    if([textfield.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!!" message:@"Enter the file name" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else if(textfield.text!= nil)
    {
        foldername1= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithString:textfield.text]];
        NSLog(@"foldername is: %@", foldername1);
    }
    ViewController2 *view2= [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Next View Name" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: is your application having navigation controller

Comment: You need to remove the segue from your button. Look at the explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Segue-based navigation:**

Remove the segue connecting OK button to View Controller 2 and add a manual segue between View Controller 1 and View Controller 2. Then implement the following code:

```
-(IBAction) okButton: (id) sender
{
    if(textfield.text.length == 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!!" 
                                                        message:@"Enter the file name" 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        foldername1 = textfield.text;
        NSLog(@"foldername is: %@", foldername1);

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
    }
}
```

**Code-based navigation:**

```
-(IBAction) okButton: (id) sender
{
    if(textfield.text.length == 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!!" 
                                                        message:@"Enter the file name" 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        foldername1 = textfield.text;
        NSLog(@"foldername is: %@", foldername1);

        ViewController2 *view2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Next View Name"
                                                                   bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

This assumes you're using ARC and that `foldername1` is a strong ivar / property.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to assign ViewController1 as the delegate of UIAlertView since I am new in this field?

Comment: Sorry to tell, but this is not going to help. There are two actions on the button: click and segue. No matter what you do in the click handler, the segue will happen.

Comment: This is the best answer and correct way to do it.
To assign ViewController1 as delegate of UIAlertView ... in your interface (.h) simply add <UIAlertViewDelegate> like so: 

ViewController1: UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> 

Then where you declare your alertView also add: alert.delegate = self. Now your ViewController will be able to catch UIAlertView delegate mathods described in the above link.

Comment: @allprog the op never mentioned anything about having a segue hooked up to the button so this answer assumes that it doesn't have one. Additionally the fact that the op has code to instantiate and push the second view controller onto the navigation stack further supports this understanding.

Comment: "when I have not connected the ok-button to the ViewController2 in Interface Builder" this is the segue I'm talking about

Comment: As I understood, the alert view needs to appear only if no transition is needed. With your solution the transition happens no matter what is the textfield's value.

Comment: Ah I'd missed the point about connecting the OK button in Interface Builder. My original answer did not modify the logic for showing the alert view, only when/how view controller 2 was instantiated and displayed, I've updated my answer and hopefully it's clearer now :)

Comment: Much better. However, it would be better to not just cure the symptom but also address the cause. That is, the original poster should go and read through a bunch of tutorials before proceeding as it is clear that they are not aware of the way navigation should be implemented. You will never be able to give enough information in an answer. Good answers for such questions on stack overflow are typically short and try to give and explanation and solution for the error and pointers to more info that helps the asker understand the fundamental issue.

Comment: Your code still executes the transition, no matter what. Dismissing the alert view should not result in transition. Transition happens only if the text field is filled in. The poster needs to do nothing else than remove the segue, and the code will work as it is now.

Comment: The op's code would always cause view controller 2 to be pushed onto the stack regardless of whether or not a segue is connected to the button - view2 is getting instantiated and pushed at the end of `okButton:` regardless of the state of the text field. I've updated my answer and it should work as required now.

Comment: @allprog "Good answers for such questions on stack overflow are typically short and try to give and explanation and solution for the error and pointers to more info that helps the asker understand the fundamental issue" good advice, I'm admittedly new to answering on SO and will take this onboard :)

Comment: And don't forget to upvote, it costs nothing. I always to that if it is a good question or answer or someone who just helped me.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a segue to a button, then you should not give it a click handler. Simply remove the segue from the button and the code should be Ok since you are using `pushViewController:animated:` to navigate instead of navigating with a segue.

Normally you would create a segue from view controller 1 to viwe controller 2, name it with an identifier, and activate that in code with the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method. Like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"selectedIdentifierForTheSegue" sender:self];
```

For more info this is a pretty good tutorial for implementing navigation: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Answer (score 0):

just writedown

```
return;
```

below [alert show]; line then it just shows an alert and not navigate to the nextview.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(IBAction) okButton: (id) sender
{
if(textfield.text.length==0)
{
    UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!!" message:@"Enter the file name" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if(textfield.text.length!=0)
{
foldername1= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithString:textfield.text]];
NSLog(@"foldername is: %@", foldername1);
}
ViewController2 *view2= [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Next View Name" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Ok. Can you please tell me if i have to connect the Ok- button to next ViewController2 manually or its not required?

Answer (score 0):

To push view controller:

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" 
                                                             bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

And also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062837/navigate-to-new-page-on-button-click-in-iphone/11063042#11063042).